# Setting a file to file object in VBA

Tags: vba

I want to check and see if a .txt file exits.

If it does I want to write to it.

If it does not I want to create it and write to it.

My problem is if the file exists I don't know how to set the fso object to the file so that I can write to it. Can you help?

```
Sub WriteToTxtFile()
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile As Object
Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\file1.txt"

If Len(Dir(DirFile)) = 0 Then 'if the file does not exist create it
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(FilePath)
    oFile.WriteLine "# , Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, VWAP"
    oFile.WriteLine "1/1/2015, 10,10,10,10,10,10"
Else
    Set oFile = ???.(FilePath) 'i know the file exists but what do I put here to access it?
    oFile.WriteLine "# , Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, VWAP"
    oFile.WriteLine "1/1/2015, 10,10,10,10,10,10"
End If

oFile.Close
Set fso = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following subroutine to append text to an existing file instead

```
Sub AppendTxt(sFile As String, sText As String)
    Dim FileNumber As Integer
    FileNumber = FreeFile                   
    Open sFile For Append As #FileNumber   
    Print #FileNumber, sText                
    Close #FileNumber                    
End Sub
```